# List of Rules for Site

Tags: discussion

Am I missing something or is there no easily accessible list of rules for the site.  It's frustrating as someone who is trying to help other people to have a well received answer be deleted and the person quote some accepted answer in the meta as a rule.  I've even had cases where I looked first in the meta and found an accepted answer supporting the way I answered a question on the main site and still had the question deleted.

Same thing with comments. I've posted comments seeking clarification on the question and had them deleted with no reason given and no response when I asked why.

Comment: This post could serve as a place holder pointing to meta questions that explain 'how things are done' here.

Comment: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3177/1599 I asked people to start writing FAQ proposals/ offer suggestions in the answers there. If we have a few proposal posts we can start combining them into a proper FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the [help page](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help). For more detailed rules there is this [meta](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/).

And comments are by definition subject to deletion, they are meant to be only temporary. What happened is, either your clarification request was fruitful, the OP has edited his question accordingly. Therefore your comment would be no longer needed and therefore removed. Or another possibility is that a mod wanted to clean up the comment section and removed yours with all the others.

Keep in mind that this stack is still in beta and its [meta](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/) is not as ripe as on out-of-beta stacks

Edit: I am all for a FAQ post that would always stick to the top of meta. It would function like an index page to the most important rules and decisions. But I don't know if this is even possible. And we *do* have a search bar already, but it just isn't as reliablke as having a sticky FAQ post.

Comment: I think that, in light of the new "back it up" rule, the help page about answering questions needs to be updated as it mentions nothing about. It actually kind of goes against it as it says "brevity is acceptable"

Comment: @Kevin, I agree that the help page about answering might not be the most fitting for a subjective site... But I don't know if we can customize that, it seems to be the same across SE. That why I linked you a bunch of other links underneath your answer, and I guess it would be a good idea to work all of that into a single FAQ ;)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell It can be edited - we just need to make it very specific to the site and have to understand that it won't be automatically updated in the future when the rest of the default ones are updated... We need to write up the text and get people happy with it and then ask the CMs to help us out.